# Flask API connection timed out

Tags: python, api, amazon-ec2, flask, timeout

I have coded a Flask API which is working fine for localhost for this query

```
curl -i http://localhost:5500/api/v1.0/search?query=keyword
```

But I am facing connection timed out issues, when I change the address from localhost to server ip/domain.

```
curl -i http://serverdomain.com:5500/api/v1.0/search?query=keyword
```

I have tried changing timeout in apache2 config files and also EC2 load balancers, but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Is port 5500 open in the EC2 firewall?

Comment: I have enabled all traffic for both inbound & outbound for testing, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Flask server is been configured to listen on all IPs. To do so, start the server with the host parameter set to '0.0.0.0'.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```